# SQL or Spring Data: Select rows in one table and order by attributes of another table

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Spring-Boot with Spring Data. I have 2 tables: `Chat` and `Messages` that have no relationship.

[image]
[image]

The `Message` table has an attribute named `chatId` with which I can match the corresponding `Chat` by his `id` attribute.

So my issue is: How can I fetch all `Chats` and order them each by their **last** created `Message's` `creationDate` attribute using **Spring Data** `@Query` or **native SQL** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT chat.*       /* !! replace asterisk with fields list */
FROM chat
JOIN message ON chat.id = message.chatid
GROUP BY chat.*     /* specify the same fields list */
ORDER BY MAX(message.creationDate) ASC /* or DESC */
```